# Silverlight AutoCompletetBox item source refresh?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

At first the data retrieved and made item source of AutoCompleteBox1 is nothing.

Then at refocus, the data(list) to be made itemsource has some records,

### problem

The item source of the autocompletebox 1 is not refreshed!.

Help please.

> The new items added to the list must  become the itemsource of the autocomplete

### Code

```
 Sub AssignToAutoCompleteOfDetails()
    ''load auto complete box
    For Each abcd In DomainService_EditCompany.GECODs
        If abcd.codCode = AutoCompleteBox2.Text.Trim Then
            list_company.Add(abcd.codDesc.ToString())
        End If
    Next
    AutoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = list_company
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because even though `list_company` is getting updated with the data, the UI doesn't know there has been a change. To tackle this Silverlight has an interface know as `INotifyPropertyChanged` which could be implemented and bound to a UI control.

But in your case all you have to do is to replace the `List<string>` with `ObservableCollection<string>` and add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`